# I believe this menu is from an old version of blender. How can I find it in 2.8?

Tags: add-on, import

I'm trying to follow an old doc on importing daz3d characters into blender.
Does anyone know where this section will be in 2.8
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Runtime tab? It's not that old as it's not in 2.78.

Comment: It's ok I found it thanks all
It's in the top right tab
https://postimg.cc/dDQ0xrL2